# display original image color with UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone

I used codes below to display a image on an UIBarButtonItem

```
UIBarButtonItem *myButtonItem;
myButtonItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(pressB:)];
```

but the image color is two colors(red/blue), but the image displayed on the ButtonItem is white.

Iy looks like IOS change it to white color automatically.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of just alloc initWithImage: if you like to add same image on all UIBarButtonItems in your app you can us this method in appdelegae.m

```
- (void)customizeAppearance
{
     // Customize the UIBarButtonItem 

    // Create resizable images
    UIImage *button30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_textured_30"] 
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
    UIImage *button24 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_textured_24"] 
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button30 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button24 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
}
```